# Unable to unset an array in Codeigniter controller

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, unset

The array that I am trying to unset an array $old_que_ans_session, which is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [home] => https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bmimagedump/uploads/interior/design/1531557190.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [home] => https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bmimagedump/uploads/interior/design/1533365337.jpg
        )

)
```

In the controller my function is

```
$id_image[$da] = $this->input->post('id');
if(array_search($id_image, array_column($old_que_ans_session,$da)!==false))
                        {
                            $key1=array_search($id_image, array_column($old_que_ans_session,$da));
                            unset($old_que_ans_session[$key1]);
                        }
```

Where $da is home. Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: First establish that your condition is resolving to true. Otherwise the unset code won't run.

Comment: Yes, the condition is true and it works fine.

Comment: What's the `$da` value?

Comment: array_column($old_que_ans_session,$da) this value it get empty array can you please tell me $da  value

Comment: It is the second segment of the URI and it's value is home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error here

Condition should be:

```
if(array_search($id_image, array_column($old_que_ans_session,$da))!==false)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can unset the array value. But, as I see in your code, there are some issues:

```
array_column($old_que_ans_session,$da)!==false
```

Why we need to check the condition like that. I think we don't need. Because the `array_column` will return an empty array if `$old_que_ans_session` doesn't have `$da` column. Maybe this is your mistake.

You can simple check:

```
if($key = array_search($id_image, array_column($old_que_ans_session,$da))){
   unset($old_que_ans_session[$key]);
}
```

Comment: I tried that, which is without array_column($old_que_ans_session,$da)!==false but still it does not unset it.